# UITableViewCells displaying over cells of other types

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 classes of cell in a tableView.  One is sort of a title card, displaying the user's name and photo, and the ones below it are displaying 5 of the user's menu items.  My configuration for this is below:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0{
        let cell = self.menuTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userInfoCard", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userInfoCard

        //Load data

        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = self.menuTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! menuItemCell
```

Here I load the various item names from their respective arrays.
Because indexPath 0 is occupied, my first menu card won't show
unless I do all of the weird resetting below with the - 1s

```
        cell.itemName.text = self.itemNames[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.itemPrice.text = self.itemPrices[indexPath.row - 1]
        cell.itemDescription.text = self.itemDescriptions[indexPath.row - 1]

        return cell
    }

}
```

I understand why the first item doesn't load, but is this the proper solution to make all of the menu items appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use UITableView Sections. By this you won't need that tricky manipulation**

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 2;
    }
```

Now in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        let cell = self.menuTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userInfoCard", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userInfoCard

        //Load data

        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = self.menuTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! menuItemCell

        //row starts from 0 with section 1
        // No subtraction needed
        cell.itemName.text = self.itemNames[indexPath.row]
    }
```